# Unmet dependencies in apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop-full

Tags: ros, packages, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to install Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04.
When I enter `sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop-full`, I am getting the following error messages.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-hydro-desktop-full : Depends: ros-hydro-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: ros-hydro-mobile but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: ros-hydro-perception but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: ros-hydro-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade`, and `apt-get -f install`, but I am still getting the same error.

Can anybody know how to solve this problem?

When I use aptitude instead I got the following result: (it is really long..)

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  collada-dom-dev{a} collada-dom2.4-dp-base{a} collada-dom2.4-dp-dev{a} 
  docgenerator{a} ffmpeg{a} fltk1.3-doc{a} fluid{a} gazebo{a} 
  generatorrunner{a} hddtemp{a} libapiextractor-dev{a} libapiextractor0.10{a} 
  libasound2-dev{ab} libassimp-dev{a} libassimp2{a} libatk1.0-dev{a} 
  libav-tools{a} libavcodec-dev{a} libavcodec-extra-53{ab} libavdevice53{a} 
  libavfilter2{a} libavformat-dev{a} libavformat-extra-53{ab} 
  libavutil-dev{a} libavutil-extra-51{ab} libbullet{a} libbullet-dev{a} 
  libcaca-dev{a} libcairo2-dev{ab} libcegui-mk2-0.7.5{a} libcegui-mk2-dev{a} 
  libcppunit-1.12-1{a} libcppunit-dev{a} libcurl4-openssl-dev{a} 
  libdevil-dev{a} libdevil1c2{a} libflann-dev{a} libflann1{a} 
  libfltk-cairo1.3{a} libfltk-forms1.3{a} libfltk-gl1.3{a} 
  libfltk-images1.3{a} libfltk1.1-dev{ab} libfltk1.3{a} libfltk1.3-dev{ab} 
  libfontconfig1-dev{ab} libfreeimage-dev{a} libfreeimage3{a} 
  libfreetype6-dev{ab} libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev{a} libgenrunner-dev{a} 
  libgenrunner0.6{a} libgeos-3.2.2{a} libgeos-c1{a} libgl2ps-dev{a} 
  libgl2ps0{a} libglib2.0-dev{ab} libgnutls-dev{ab} libgtk2.0-dev{a} 
  libhdf5-serial-1.8.4{a} libidn11-dev{a} libjasper-dev{a} libjpeg-dev{a} 
  libjpeg-turbo8-dev{ab} libjpeg8-dev{a} libjs-sphinxdoc{a} 
  libjs-underscore{a} liblcms1-dev{a} liblodo3.0{a} liblua5.1-0-dev{a} 
  libmng-dev{a} libnetcdf-dev{a} libnetcdf6{a} libodbc1{a} libogg-dev{a} 
  libogre-1.7.4{a} libogre-dev{a} libois-1.3.0{a} libopencv-core2.3{a} 
  libopencv-highgui2.3{a} libopencv-imgproc2.3{a} libopenjpeg2{a} 
  libopenni-dev{a} libopenni-sensor-primesense0{a} libopenni0{a} 
  libpango1.0-dev{ab} libpcl-1.7-all{a} libpcl-1.7-all-dev{a} 
  libpcl-1.7-bin{a} libpcl-1.7-doc{a} libpcl-apps-1.7{a} 
  libpcl-apps-1.7-dev{a} libpcl-common-1.7{a} libpcl-common-1.7-dev{a} 
  libpcl-features-1.7{a} libpcl-features-1.7-dev{a} libpcl-filters-1.7{a} 
  libpcl-filters-1.7-dev{a} libpcl-geometry-1.7-dev{a} libpcl-io-1.7{a} 
  libpcl-io-1.7-dev{a} libpcl-kdtree-1.7{a} libpcl-kdtree-1.7-dev{a} 
  libpcl-keypoints-1.7{a} libpcl-keypoints-1.7-dev{a} libpcl-octree-1.7{a} 
  libpcl-octree-1.7-dev{a} libpcl-outofcore-1.7{a} 
  libpcl-outofcore-1.7-dev{a} libpcl-people-1.7{a} libpcl-people-1.7-dev{a} 
  libpcl-recognition-1.7{a} libpcl-recognition-1.7-dev{a} 
  libpcl-registration-1.7{a} libpcl-registration-1.7-dev{a} 
  libpcl-sample-consensus-1.7{a} libpcl-sample-consensus-1.7-dev{a} 
  libpcl-search-1.7{a} libpcl-search-1.7-dev{a} libpcl-segmentation-1.7{a} 
  libpcl-segmentation-1.7-dev{a} libpcl-surface-1.7{a} 
  libpcl-surface-1.7-dev{a} libpcl-tracking-1.7{a} libpcl-tracking-1.7-dev{a} 
  libpcl-visualization-1.7{a} libpcl-visualization-1.7-dev{a} 
  libplayerc++3.0{a} libplayerc3.0{a} libplayercommon3.0{a} 
  libplayercore3.0{a} libplayerdrivers3.0{a} libplayerinterface3.0{a} 
  libplayerjpeg3.0{a} libplayertcp3.0{a} libplayerwkb3.0{a} libpmap3.0{a} 
  libpng12-dev{a} libpoco-dev{a} libpococrypto9{a} libpocodata9{a} 
  libpocofoundation9{a} libpocomysql9{a} libpoconet9{a} libpoconetssl9{a} 
  libpocoodbc9{a} libpocosqlite9{a} libpocoutil9{a} libpocoxml9{a} 
  libpocozip9{a} libpostproc-extra-52{ab} libprotobuf-dev{a} 
  libprotobuf-lite7{a} libpulse-dev{ab} libpyside-dev{a} libpyside-py3-1.1{a} 
  libpyside1.1{a} libpython3.2{a} libqhull-dev{a} libqhull5{a} libqwt-dev{a} 
  libqwt5-qt4{a} libqwt6{a} libreadline-dev{a} librtmp-dev{a} 
  libsdl-image1.2-dev{a} libsdl1.2-dev{a} libshiboken-dev{a} 
  libshiboken-py3-1.1{a} libshiboken1.1{a} libsilly{a} libslang2-dev{a} 
  libstatgrab6{a} libswscale-dev{a} libswscale-extra-2{ab} libtbb-dev{a} 
  libtbb2{a} libtheora-dev{a} libtiff4-dev{ab} libusb-1.0-0-dev{a} 
  libv4l-dev{ab} libvtk5-dev{a} libvtk5-qt4-dev{a} libvtk5.8{a} 
  libvtk5.8-qt4{a} libxaw7-dev{a} libxcomposite-dev{a} libxcursor-dev{a} 
  libxdamage-dev{a} libxerces-c3.1{a} libxfixes-dev{a} libxft-dev{a} 
  libxi-dev{a} libxml2-dev{ab} libxpm-dev{a} libxrandr-dev{a} 
  libxrender-dev{a} libxss-dev{a} libzzip-0-13{a} libzzip-dev{a} 
  openni-utils{a} python-epydoc{a} python-jinja2{a} python-kitchen{a} 
  python-netifaces{a} python-opengl{a} python-psutil{a} python-pydot{a} 
  python-pyside{a} python-pyside.phonon{a} python-pyside.qtcore{a} 
  python-pyside.qtdeclarative{a} python-pyside.qtgui{a} 
  python-pyside.qthelp{a} python-pyside.qtnetwork{a} 
  python-pyside.qtopengl{a} python-pyside.qtscript{a} python-pyside.qtsql{a} 
  python-pyside.qtsvg{a} python-pyside.qttest{a} python-pyside.qtuitools{a} 
  python-pyside.qtwebkit{a} python-pyside.qtxml{a} python-qt4-dev{a} 
  python-qt4-gl{a} python-qwt5-qt4{a} python-sip-dev{a} python-sphinx{a} 
  python3.2{a} python3.2-minimal{a} robot-player{a} ros-hydro-actionlib{a} 
  ros-hydro-actionlib-msgs{a} ros-hydro-actionlib-tutorials{a} 
  ros-hydro-amcl{a} ros-hydro-angles{a} ros-hydro-base-local-planner{a} 
  ros-hydro-bfl{a} ros-hydro-bond{a} ros-hydro-bond-core{a} 
  ros-hydro-bondcpp{a} ros-hydro-bondpy{a} ros-hydro-camera-calibration{a} 
  ros-hydro-camera-calibration-parsers{a} ros-hydro-camera-info-manager{a} 
  ros-hydro-carrot-planner{a} ros-hydro-catkin{a} ros-hydro-class-loader{a} 
  ros-hydro-clear-costmap-recovery{a} ros-hydro-collada-parser{a} 
  ros-hydro-collada-urdf{a} ros-hydro-common-msgs{a} 
  ros-hydro-common-tutorials{a} ros-hydro-compressed-depth-image-transport{a} 
  ros-hydro-compressed-image-transport{a} ros-hydro-console-bridge{a} 
  ros-hydro-control-msgs{a} ros-hydro-costmap-2d{a} ros-hydro-cpp-common{a} 
  ros-hydro-cv-bridge{a} ros-hydro-depth-image-proc{a} ros-hydro-desktop{a} 
  ros-hydro-desktop-full ros-hydro-diagnostic-aggregator{a} 
  ros-hydro-diagnostic-analysis{a} ros-hydro-diagnostic-common-diagnostics{a} 
  ros-hydro-diagnostic-msgs{a} ros-hydro-diagnostic-updater{a} 
  ros-hydro-diagnostics{a} ros-hydro-driver-base{a} 
  ros-hydro-driver-common{a} ros-hydro-dwa-local-planner{a} 
  ros-hydro-dynamic-reconfigure{a} ros-hydro-eigen-conversions{a} 
  ros-hydro-eigen-stl-containers{a} ros-hydro-executive-smach{a} 
  ros-hydro-fake-localization{a} ros-hydro-filters{a} 
  ros-hydro-gazebo-msgs{a} ros-hydro-gazebo-plugins{a} 
  ros-hydro-gazebo-ros{a} ros-hydro-gazebo-ros-pkgs{a} ros-hydro-gencpp{a} 
  ros-hydro-genlisp{a} ros-hydro-genmsg{a} ros-hydro-genpy{a} 
  ros-hydro-geometric-shapes{a} ros-hydro-geometry{a} 
  ros-hydro-geometry-experimental{a} ros-hydro-geometry-msgs{a} 
  ros-hydro-geometry-tutorials{a} ros-hydro-gmapping{a} 
  ros-hydro-image-common{a} ros-hydro-image-geometry{a} 
  ros-hydro-image-pipeline{a} ros-hydro-image-proc{a} 
  ros-hydro-image-rotate{a} ros-hydro-image-transport{a} 
  ros-hydro-image-transport-plugins{a} ros-hydro-image-view{a} 
  ros-hydro-interactive-marker-tutorials{a} ros-hydro-interactive-markers{a} 
  ros-hydro-joint-state-publisher{a} ros-hydro-kdl-conversions{a} 
  ros-hydro-kdl-parser{a} ros-hydro-laser-assembler{a} 
  ros-hydro-laser-filters{a} ros-hydro-laser-geometry{a} 
  ros-hydro-laser-pipeline{a} ros-hydro-librviz-tutorial{a} 
  ros-hydro-map-msgs{a} ros-hydro-map-server{a} ros-hydro-media-export{a} 
  ros-hydro-message-filters{a} ros-hydro-message-generation{a} 
  ros-hydro-message-runtime{a} ros-hydro-mk{a} ros-hydro-mobile{a} 
  ros-hydro-move-base{a} ros-hydro-move-base-msgs{a} 
  ros-hydro-move-slow-and-clear{a} ros-hydro-nav-core{a} 
  ros-hydro-nav-msgs{a} ros-hydro-navfn{a} ros-hydro-navigation{a} 
  ros-hydro-nodelet{a} ros-hydro-nodelet-core{a} 
  ros-hydro-nodelet-topic-tools{a} ros-hydro-nodelet-tutorial-math{a} 
  ros-hydro-octomap{a} ros-hydro-opencv2{a} ros-hydro-openslam-gmapping{a} 
  ros-hydro-orocos-kdl{a} ros-hydro-pcl-conversions{a} ros-hydro-pcl-msgs{a} 
  ros-hydro-pcl-ros{a} ros-hydro-perception{a} ros-hydro-perception-pcl{a} 
  ros-hydro-pluginlib{a} ros-hydro-pluginlib-tutorials{a} 
  ros-hydro-polled-camera{a} ros-hydro-python-qt-binding{a} 
  ros-hydro-qt-dotgraph{a} ros-hydro-qt-gui{a} ros-hydro-qt-gui-app{a} 
  ros-hydro-qt-gui-core{a} ros-hydro-qt-gui-cpp{a} 
  ros-hydro-qt-gui-py-common{a} ros-hydro-random-numbers{a} 
  ros-hydro-resource-retriever{a} ros-hydro-robot{a} ros-hydro-robot-model{a} 
  ros-hydro-robot-pose-ekf{a} ros-hydro-robot-state-publisher{a} 
  ros-hydro-ros{a} ros-hydro-ros-base{a} ros-hydro-ros-comm{a} 
  ros-hydro-ros-full{a} ros-hydro-ros-tutorials{a} ros-hydro-rosbag{a} 
  ros-hydro-rosbag-migration-rule{a} ros-hydro-rosbash{a} 
  ros-hydro-rosboost-cfg{a} ros-hydro-rosbuild{a} ros-hydro-rosclean{a} 
  ros-hydro-rosconsole{a} ros-hydro-rosconsole-bridge{a} ros-hydro-roscpp{a} 
  ros-hydro-roscpp-serialization{a} ros-hydro-roscpp-traits{a} 
  ros-hydro-roscpp-tutorials{a} ros-hydro-roscreate{a} 
  ros-hydro-rosdoc-lite{a} ros-hydro-rosgraph{a} ros-hydro-rosgraph-msgs{a} 
  ros-hydro-roslang{a} ros-hydro-roslaunch{a} ros-hydro-roslib{a} 
  ros-hydro-roslisp{a} ros-hydro-rosmake{a} ros-hydro-rosmaster{a} 
  ros-hydro-rosmsg{a} ros-hydro-rosnode{a} ros-hydro-rosout{a} 
  ros-hydro-rospack{a} ros-hydro-rosparam{a} ros-hydro-rospy{a} 
  ros-hydro-rospy-tutorials{a} ros-hydro-rosservice{a} ros-hydro-rostest{a} 
  ros-hydro-rostime{a} ros-hydro-rostopic{a} ros-hydro-rosunit{a} 
  ros-hydro-roswtf{a} ros-hydro-rotate-recovery{a} ros-hydro-rqt-action{a} 
  ros-hydro-rqt-bag{a} ros-hydro-rqt-bag-plugins{a} 
  ros-hydro-rqt-common-plugins{a} ros-hydro-rqt-console{a} 
  ros-hydro-rqt-dep{a} ros-hydro-rqt-graph{a} ros-hydro-rqt-gui{a} 
  ros-hydro-rqt-gui-cpp{a} ros-hydro-rqt-gui-py{a} 
  ros-hydro-rqt-image-view{a} ros-hydro-rqt-launch{a} 
  ros-hydro-rqt-logger-level{a} ros-hydro-rqt-moveit{a} ros-hydro-rqt-msg{a} 
  ros-hydro-rqt-nav-view{a} ros-hydro-rqt-plot{a} ros-hydro-rqt-pose-view{a} 
  ros-hydro-rqt-publisher{a} ros-hydro-rqt-py-common{a} 
  ros-hydro-rqt-py-console{a} ros-hydro-rqt-reconfigure{a} 
  ros-hydro-rqt-robot-dashboard{a} ros-hydro-rqt-robot-monitor{a} 
  ros-hydro-rqt-robot-plugins{a} ros-hydro-rqt-robot-steering{a} 
  ros-hydro-rqt-runtime-monitor{a} ros-hydro-rqt-rviz{a} 
  ros-hydro-rqt-service-caller{a} ros-hydro-rqt-shell{a} ros-hydro-rqt-srv{a} 
  ros-hydro-rqt-tf-tree{a} ros-hydro-rqt-top{a} ros-hydro-rqt-topic{a} 
  ros-hydro-rqt-web{a} ros-hydro-rviz{a} ros-hydro-rviz-plugin-tutorials{a} 
  ros-hydro-rviz-python-tutorial{a} ros-hydro-self-test{a} 
  ros-hydro-sensor-msgs{a} ros-hydro-shape-msgs{a} ros-hydro-shape-tools{a} 
  ros-hydro-simulators{a} ros-hydro-smach{a} ros-hydro-smach-msgs{a} 
  ros-hydro-smach-ros{a} ros-hydro-smclib{a} ros-hydro-stage{a} 
  ros-hydro-stage-ros{a} ros-hydro-std-msgs{a} ros-hydro-std-srvs{a} 
  ros-hydro-stereo-image-proc{a} ros-hydro-stereo-msgs{a} ros-hydro-tf{a} 
  ros-hydro-tf-conversions{a} ros-hydro-tf2{a} ros-hydro-tf2-bullet{a} 
  ros-hydro-tf2-geometry-msgs{a} ros-hydro-tf2-kdl{a} ros-hydro-tf2-msgs{a} 
  ros-hydro-tf2-py{a} ros-hydro-tf2-ros{a} ros-hydro-tf2-tools{a} 
  ros-hydro-theora-image-transport{a} ros-hydro-timestamp-tools{a} 
  ros-hydro-topic-tools{a} ros-hydro-trajectory-msgs{a} 
  ros-hydro-turtle-actionlib{a} ros-hydro-turtle-tf{a} ros-hydro-turtlesim{a} 
  ros-hydro-urdf{a} ros-hydro-urdf-parser-plugin{a} 
  ros-hydro-urdf-tutorial{a} ros-hydro-urdfdom{a} 
  ros-hydro-urdfdom-headers{a} ros-hydro-vision-opencv{a} 
  ros-hydro-visualization-marker-tutorials{a} ros-hydro-visualization-msgs{a} 
  ros-hydro-visualization-tutorials{a} ros-hydro-viz{a} 
  ros-hydro-voxel-grid{a} ros-hydro-xacro{a} ros-hydro-xmlrpcpp{a} sbcl{a} 
  sdformat{a} shiboken{a} sphinx-common{a} sphinx-doc{a} tango-icon-theme{a} 
  tcl8.5-dev{a} texlive-fonts-recommended{a} texlive-fonts-recommended-doc{a} 
  tipa{a} tk8.5-dev{a} x11proto-composite-dev{a} x11proto-damage-dev{a} 
  x11proto-fixes-dev{a} x11proto-randr-dev{a} x11proto-render-dev{a} 
  x11proto-scrnsaver-dev{a} yaml-cpp{a} 
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  firefox-locale-zh-hans{u} gir1.2-json-1.0{u} gir1.2-timezonemap-1.0{u} 
  gir1.2-xkl-1.0{u} kde-l10n-engb{u} kde-l10n-zhcn{u} language-pack-kde-en{u} 
  language-pack-kde-en-base{u} language-pack-kde-zh-hans{u} 
  language-pack-kde-zh-hans-base{u} language-pack-zh-hans{u} 
  language-pack-zh-hans-base{u} lesstif2{u} linux-headers-3.2.0-29{u} 
  linux-headers-3.2.0-29-generic{u} 
0 packages upgraded, 496 newly installed, 15 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 251 MB of archives. After unpacking 797 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libavformat-extra-53 : Conflicts: libavformat53 but 4:0.8.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 is installed.
 libjpeg-turbo8-dev : Depends: libjpeg-turbo8 (= 1.1.90+svn733-0ubuntu4) but 1.1.90+svn733-0ubuntu4.1 is installed.
 libasound2-dev : Depends: libasound2 (= 1.0.25-1ubuntu10) but 1.0.25-1ubuntu10.1 is installed.
 libtiff4-dev : Depends: libtiff4 (= 3.9.5-2ubuntu1) but 3.9.5-2ubuntu1.4 is installed.
                Depends: libtiffxx0c2 (= 3.9.5-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed.
 libavutil-extra-51 : Conflicts: libavutil51 but 4:0.8.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 is installed.
 libfontconfig1-dev : Depends: libfontconfig1 (= 2.8.0-3ubuntu9) but 2.8.0-3ubuntu9.1 is installed.
 libfltk1.3-dev : Conflicts: libfltk-dev which is a virtual package.
 libpostproc-extra-52 : Conflicts: libpostproc52 but 4:0.8.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 is installed.
 libswscale-extra-2 : Conflicts: libswscale2 but 4:0.8.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 is installed.
 libglib2.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.32.1-0ubuntu2) but 2.32.3-0ubuntu1 is installed.
                  Depends: libglib2.0-bin (= 2.32.1-0ubuntu2) but 2.32.3-0ubuntu1 is installed.
 libxml2-dev : Depends: libxml2 (= 2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4) but 2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.3 is installed.
 libcairo2-dev : Depends: libcairo2 (= 1.10.2-6.1ubuntu2) but 1.10.2-6.1ubuntu3 is installed.
                 Depends: libcairo-gobject2 (= 1.10.2-6.1ubuntu2) but 1.10.2-6.1ubuntu3 is installed.
                 Depends: libcairo-script-interpreter2 (= 1.10.2-6.1ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed.
                 Depends: libpixman-1-dev (>= 0.18.4) but it is not going to be installed.
                 Depends: libxcb-render0-dev (>= 0.9.92) but it is not going to be installed.
                 Depends: libxcb-shm0-dev but it is not going to be installed.
 libpango1.0-dev : Depends: libpango1.0-0 (= 1.30.0-0ubuntu2) but 1.30.0-0ubuntu3.1 is installed.
                   Depends: gir1.2-pango-1.0 (= 1.30.0-0ubuntu2) but 1.30.0-0ubuntu3.1 is installed.
 libfreetype6-dev : Depends: libfreetype6 (= 2.4.8-1ubuntu2) but 2.4.8-1ubuntu2.1 is installed.
 libfltk1.1-dev : Conflicts: libfltk-dev which is a virtual package.
 libpulse-dev : Depends: libpulse0 (= 1:1.1-0ubuntu15) but 1:1.1-0ubuntu15.2 is installed.
                Depends: libpulse-mainloop-glib0 (= 1:1.1-0ubuntu15) but 1:1.1-0ubuntu15.2 is installed.
                Depends: libavahi-client-dev but it is not going to be installed.
 libgnutls-dev : Depends: libgnutls26 (= 2.12.14-5ubuntu3) but 2.12.14-5ubuntu3.1 is installed.
                 Depends: libgnutlsxx27 (= 2.12.14-5ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed.
                 Depends: libgnutls-openssl27 (= 2.12.14-5ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed.
                 Depends: libgcrypt11-dev (>= 1.4.0) but it is not going to be installed.
                 Depends: libtasn1-3-dev (>= 0.3.4) but it is not going to be installed.
                 Depends: libp11-kit-dev (>= 0.4) but it is not going to be installed.
 libavcodec-extra-53 : Conflicts: libavcodec53 but 4:0.8.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 is installed.
 libv4l-dev : Depends: libv4l-0 (= 0.8.6-1ubuntu1) but 0.8.6-1ubuntu2 is installed.
              Depends: libv4lconvert0 (= 0.8.6-1ubuntu1) but 0.8.6-1ubuntu2 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

       Keep the following packages at their current version:       
1)       ffmpeg [Not Installed]                                    
2)       gazebo [Not Installed]                                    
3)       libasound2-dev [Not Installed]                            
4)       libatk1.0-dev [Not Installed]                             
5)       libav-tools [Not Installed]                               
6)       libavcodec-dev [Not Installed]                            
7)       libavcodec-extra-53 [Not Installed]                       
8)       libavdevice53 [Not Installed]                             
9)       libavfilter2 [Not Installed]                              
10)      libavformat-dev [Not Installed]                           
11)      libavformat-extra-53 [Not Installed]                      
12)      libavutil-dev [Not Installed]                             
13)      libavutil-extra-51 [Not Installed]                        
14)      libcairo2-dev [Not Installed]                             
15)      libcegui-mk2-dev [Not Installed]                          
16)      libcurl4-openssl-dev [Not Installed]                      
17)      libdevil-dev [Not Installed]                              
18)      libfltk1.1-dev [Not Installed]                            
19)      libfontconfig1-dev [Not Installed]                        
20)      libfreetype6-dev [Not Installed]                          
21)      libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev [Not Installed]                      
22)      libglib2.0-dev [Not Installed]                            
23)      libgnutls-dev [Not Installed]                             
24)      libgtk2.0-dev [Not Installed]                             
25)      libjpeg-dev [Not Installed]                               
26)      libjpeg-turbo8-dev [Not Installed]                        
27)      libjpeg8-dev [Not Installed]                              
28)      libmng-dev [Not Installed]                                
29)      libogre-dev [Not Installed]                               
30)      libpango1.0-dev [Not Installed]                           
31)      libpcl-1.7-all [Not Installed]                            
32)      libpcl-1.7-all-dev [Not Installed]                        
33)      libpcl-apps-1.7-dev [Not Installed]                       
34)      libpcl-io-1.7-dev [Not Installed]                         
35)      libpcl-outofcore-1.7-dev [Not Installed]                  
36)      libpcl-people-1.7-dev [Not Installed]                     
37)      libpcl-recognition-1.7-dev [Not Installed]                
38)      libpcl-visualization-1.7-dev [Not Installed]              
39)      libpostproc-extra-52 [Not Installed]                      
40)      libpulse-dev [Not Installed]                              
41)      librtmp-dev [Not Installed]                               
42)      libsdl-image1.2-dev [Not Installed]                       
43)      libsdl1.2-dev [Not Installed]                             
44)      libswscale-dev [Not Installed]                            
45)      libswscale-extra-2 [Not Installed]                        
46)      libtiff4-dev [Not Installed]                              
47)      libv4l-dev [Not Installed]                                
48)      libvtk5-dev [Not Installed]                               
49)      libvtk5-qt4-dev [Not Installed]                           
50)      libxft-dev [Not Installed]                                
51)      libxml2-dev [Not Installed]                               
52)      ros-hydro-base-local-planner [Not Installed]              
53)      ros-hydro-camera-calibration [Not Installed]              
54)      ros-hydro-carrot-planner [Not Installed]                  
55)      ros-hydro-clear-costmap-recovery [Not Installed]          
56)      ros-hydro-collada-urdf [Not Installed]                    
57)      ros-hydro-compressed-depth-image-transport [Not Installed]
58)      ros-hydro-compressed-image-transport [Not Installed]      
59)      ros-hydro-costmap-2d [Not Installed]                      
60)      ros-hydro-cv-bridge [Not Installed]                       
61)      ros-hydro-depth-image-proc [Not Installed]                
62)      ros-hydro-desktop [Not Installed]                         
63)      ros-hydro-desktop-full [Not Installed]                    
64)      ros-hydro-dwa-local-planner [Not Installed]               
65)      ros-hydro-gazebo-plugins [Not Installed]                  
66)      ros-hydro-gazebo-ros [Not Installed]                      
67)      ros-hydro-gazebo-ros-pkgs [Not Installed]                 
68)      ros-hydro-geometric-shapes [Not Installed]                
69)      ros-hydro-image-geometry [Not Installed]                  
70)      ros-hydro-image-pipeline [Not Installed]                  
71)      ros-hydro-image-proc [Not Installed]                      
72)      ros-hydro-image-rotate [Not Installed]                    
73)      ros-hydro-image-transport-plugins [Not Installed]         
74)      ros-hydro-image-view [Not Installed]                      
75)      ros-hydro-laser-filters [Not Installed]                   
76)      ros-hydro-laser-pipeline [Not Installed]                  
77)      ros-hydro-librviz-tutorial [Not Installed]                
78)      ros-hydro-map-server [Not Installed]                      
79)      ros-hydro-mobile [Not Installed]                          
80)      ros-hydro-move-base [Not Installed]                       
81)      ros-hydro-move-slow-and-clear [Not Installed]             
82)      ros-hydro-nav-core [Not Installed]                        
83)      ros-hydro-navfn [Not Installed]                           
84)      ros-hydro-navigation [Not Installed]                      
85)      ros-hydro-opencv2 [Not Installed]                         
86)      ros-hydro-pcl-conversions [Not Installed]                 
87)      ros-hydro-pcl-ros [Not Installed]                         
88)      ros-hydro-perception [Not Installed]                      
89)      ros-hydro-perception-pcl [Not Installed]                  
90)      ros-hydro-resource-retriever [Not Installed]              
91)      ros-hydro-robot [Not Installed]                           
92)      ros-hydro-robot-model [Not Installed]                     
93)      ros-hydro-ros-full [Not Installed]                        
94)      ros-hydro-rotate-recovery [Not Installed]                 
95)      ros-hydro-rqt-common-plugins [Not Installed]              
96)      ros-hydro-rqt-image-view [Not Installed]                  
97)      ros-hydro-rqt-robot-plugins [Not Installed]               
98)      ros-hydro-rqt-rviz [Not Installed]                        
99)      ros-hydro-rviz [Not Installed]                            
100)     ros-hydro-rviz-plugin-tutorials [Not Installed]           
101)     ros-hydro-rviz-python-tutorial [Not Installed]            
102)     ros-hydro-simulators [Not Installed]                      
103)     ros-hydro-stage [Not Installed]                           
104)     ros-hydro-stage-ros [Not Installed]                       
105)     ros-hydro-stereo-image-proc [Not Installed]               
106)     ros-hydro-theora-image-transport [Not Installed]          
107)     ros-hydro-vision-opencv [Not Installed]                   
108)     ros-hydro-visualization-tutorials [Not Installed]         
109)     ros-hydro-viz [Not Installed]                             
110)     tk8.5-dev [Not Installed]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/106631/unmet-dependencies-in-apt-get-install-ros-hydro-desktop-full/) by [urthkakao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9441/urthkakao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2013-12-03

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-12-03**:
Try aptitude instead of apt-get and post the suggestions it gives here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I encountered the same problem. For me, the problem was that an upgrade to ps-engine depended on a version of openni-dev that apparently more recent than what is available in 12.04. To fix it I ran aptitude as follows:

```
$ sudo aptitude install ros-hydro-desktop-full
...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ps-engine : Depends: openni-dev (>= 1.5.2.23~precise) but 1.3.2.1-4+precise2 is
installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Keep the following packages at their current version:
  [...lists 39 ROS and PCL packages that are not (and will not be) installed...]
Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

Clearly that isn't desirable, so do not accept that solution (hit 'n <enter>' in response to the question above). Then aptitude gives an alternate solution:

```
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Install the following packages:           
1)     ps-engine [5.0.3.3-3+precise1 (precise)]

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

That solution installs an earlier version of ps-engine, which can have it's dependencies met, so it works. Accept it and let aptitude do its work; that should fix your problem.

Hopefully a version of openni-dev which is compatible with the latest ps-engine will be added to the apt repositories soon...

---

Originally posted by [astrokenny](https://answers.ros.org/users/4041/astrokenny/) with karma: 78 on 2013-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [urthkakao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9441/urthkakao/) on 2013-12-08**:
Thanks. It helped to realize that I had strange dependency problem (many of them), so I had to completely remove ubuntu, and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I just ran into this same problem yesterday but was able to eventually get Hydro installed.

I had a number of dependencies which were a minor revision beyond what was compatible with Hydro, I used aptitude to correct them. You can use aptitude to install the missing packages until you get to the point where it reports no changes will be made, at that point if you select 'no' for the proposed configuration aptitude should suggest alternative dependencies.

It can be helpful to walk down the dependency tree to find the unmet/conflicting dependencies using apt-get.

e.g. if apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop-full fails, try apt-get install for the first unmet dependency listed, in this case that would be ros-hydro-desktop.
Continue trying to apt-get install the first unmet dependency listed until you finally reach the underlying conflict, at that point aptitude can be useful for suggesting an alternative.

---

Originally posted by [Jtheletter](https://answers.ros.org/users/9451/jtheletter/) with karma: 11 on 2013-12-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1